# Multiline UILabel with automatic width prefers to use 1 line

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to create a label with dynamic width. I know how to implement it in xib in usual cases.

But in my current case this label has fixed height, 2 max lines and unlimited width.

The problem is width unlimited, so iOS always writes the label in a single line. Is it possible to force fulfill the maximum number of lines first and only then increase the label size?

Comment: Hmmm... so, if the text is "This is the text" -- you want "This is" on the first line and "the text" on the second line? And if the text is "This is longer text for my two-line label", for example, you want to be able to split it so the two lines are (roughly) equal in length?

Comment: Also, you say *"unlimited width"* ... does that mean you want two lines of text, even if that stretches the label past the width of the view? Or will you have a "max width"?

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by “Is it possible to force fulfill the maximum number of lines first and only then increase the label size?” If you set a maximum width (rather than unlimited width) and set the number of lines to zero, it will figure out how many lines are needed given the constraint of maximum width. Perhaps you can edit your question to provide an example text string, what you are experiencing, and what you were hoping to achieve. As the question is currently worded, it is a bit unclear.

Comment: @DonMag yes, I want to write "This is the text" like "This is\nthe text". Text comes from outside so I can just split it into 2 strings. But you idea to find "middle space" and replace it with "\n" seems to be workable. Yes, I want to have 2 lines always and I don't have max width.

Comment: @Rob I have a limited number of strings and I have already wrote about it in my question. What is unclear in my question? iOS tries to fulfill the width first and I need to fulfill the number of lines first

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [boundingRect(with:options:attributes:context:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect)...

Assuming you have string `str`:

- calculate the height that 2 lines would require (use `"1\n2"`, for example)
- calculate the width that the `str` would require, if it was only a single line
- divide that width by 2 (we'll call it `halfWidth`)
- calculate the height of `str` limiting it's width to `halfWidth`

At this point, we've cut the width exactly in half, and that could (will almost certainly) cut a word in half. That means word-wrapping can result in the height being greater than the two-lines-height.

So we need to:

- loop
- incrementing `halfWidth` (by 8-pts seems reasonable)
- get the new bounding box height
- keep looping until the new height equals the two-lines-height

Here is a quick example. We'll use these strings for the label:

```
"First example.",
"String with some text.",
"This is a longer string for the two-line label.",
"Depending on the available width, we may run into problems if the text is too long.",
"Our final example string will be much longer than the others. This will demonstrate that, unless we also set a max-width, the calculated width will end up extending the label outside the bounds of our view (assuming we're on an iPhone in Portrait orientation).",
```

With each tap in the view, we'll calculate a "two-line-width" for the string and update the label's width constraint:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var theLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
    var labelWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    let testStrings: [String] = [
        "First example.",
        "String with some text.",
        "This is a longer string for the two-line label.",
        "Depending on the available width, we may run into problems if the text is too long.",
        "Our final example string will be much longer than the others. This will demonstrate that, unless we also set a max-width, the calculated width will end up extending the label outside the bounds of our view (assuming we're on an iPhone in Portrait orientation).",
    ]
    
    var idx: Int = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        theLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // max of two lines
        theLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        
        // whatever font you want for your label
        theLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16.0)
        
        view.addSubview(theLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // create the width constraint that we'll modify in updateLabel()
        //  using 100 here, but the initial value doesn't matter...
        labelWidthConstraint = theLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // let's put the label at 40,40
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            labelWidthConstraint,
        ])
        
        // so we can see the label frame
        theLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        
        // update the label with the first string from our array
        let s = testStrings[idx]
        updateLabel(s)
        
        let t = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(t)
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ g: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        // change the string and re-caculate the label on each tap
        idx += 1
        let s = testStrings[idx % testStrings.count]
        updateLabel(s)
    }
    
    func updateLabel(_ str: String) -> Void {
        guard let theLabelFont = theLabel.font else {
            // this should never happen, but always a
            //  good idea to properly unwrap optionals
            return
        }
        // get the calculated width
        let calcWidth: CGFloat = calcTwoLineWidth(str, fnt: theLabelFont)
        // update the label's width constraint constant
        labelWidthConstraint.constant = calcWidth
        // update the label's text
        theLabel.text = str
    }
    
    func calcTwoLineWidth(_ str: String, fnt: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        // get the height of two lines
        let twoLineHeight = "1\n2".height(withConstrainedWidth: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, font: fnt)
        // get the width of the string as a single line
        let oneLineWidth = str.width(withConstrainedHeight: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, font: fnt)
        // start with 1/2 of the full width of the string
        var halfWidth: CGFloat = ceil(oneLineWidth * 0.5)
        // get the height of the string constrained to half width
        var newHeight: CGFloat = str.height(withConstrainedWidth: halfWidth, font: fnt)
        // the string may still wrap onto a third line, so increase the width
        //  until we only need two lines
        while newHeight > twoLineHeight {
            halfWidth += 8
            newHeight = str.height(withConstrainedWidth: halfWidth, font: fnt)
        }
        return halfWidth
    }
    
}

extension String {
    func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.height)
    }
    
    func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
        let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
        let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(boundingBox.width)
    }
}
```

And here's the results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Notice that the final string is too long to fit on two lines within the bounds of our view -- which is, based on your description an comment, your desired goal.

Please note this is ***Example Code Only***.

Comment: it is not suitable for me to calc each label with a loop. The solution with "\n" based on your idea is much better

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov - Is your situation that you have a *"limited number of strings"* that are static? So you would be inserting your "\n" breaks when you write the code, instead of needing to split the string at run-time?

Comment: don't get confused - I have unlimited number of labels and limited number of labels' lines. Strings are semistatic - server defines and sends me a list of strings so they vary but I don't modify this list locally (except of this case with "\n" for display purposes)

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov - ok... so do you plan on using "\n" to split the strings based on "word count"? i.e. if you get 6 words, such as "one two three four five six" you'll put a "\n" between "three" and "four"? What happens if the string is "*Testing sample server-received string consisting of long and short words.*"? Word-splitting will result in unbalanced lines (first line will be "**Testing sample server-received string consisting**" and second line will be "**of long and short words.**"